# Telerik RadMenu XAML designer error

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, telerik, silverlight-5.0, radmenu

I have a XAML page which correctly loads in the designer when you first open the page. One of the controls on the page is a `Telerik RadMenu`. If you click on one of the RadMenuItem's in the Visual Studio designer, it causes the following exception to be thrown.

> Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>   Stack Trace:

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_InsertValue[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection, UInt32 index, CValue value)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.Collection_InsertDependencyObject[T](PresentationFrameworkCollection`1 collection, UInt32 index, DependencyObject value)
at System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection`1.InsertDependencyObject(Int32 index, DependencyObject value)
at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.InsertInternal(Int32 index, UIElement value)
```

> InnerException: None

This stops the designer from working and the only way to get it working again is to close + reopen Visual Studio. Is this a bug with my `XAML` or is it a problem which needs reporting to Telerik / Microsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a bug in Visual Studio 2012. VS 2013 does not have the problem and VS 2012 update 4 fixed the issue.